# Runas CMD - Everytime Window gains focus, I have to turn off Insert?

Tags: windows, insert, command-prompt

This is a general windows 7 question.  I log in with my normal account and then runas a command-shell with my admin account.  I use it so I can just up-arrow my last RDP connection and change a few letters to RDP into a different machine.  The problem is that recently (I don't know what changed), when I'll do something outside of that elevated command-shell and then go back into it to RDP into a different machine (up-arrow, change a few letters from the previous RDP, then hit Enter), my Insert key is always active.  So now I have to turn off Insert everytime my command-shell gains focus.

Does anyone know why this might be or what I can do to disable it?  TIA!

Comment: a reboot seems to have fixed this as it's not a default setting but if i don't reboot for awhile, this seems to repeat itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rebuild of my system stopped this behavior from happening.  I know that's not a good answer but it's the only one I found--or anyone suggested.